# Visual Studio IDE Issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide

Can someone tell me why my Ctrl+F5 disappeared in Visual Studio 2008? Its not even in the menu. In the Debug menu, All I have is Windows, Start Debugging, Step Into, Step Over, Exceptions, and Toggle Breakpoints.

I'm using the professional edition of Visual Studio 2008 and for some reason, this morning, it just vanished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-add it: Tools -> Customize... -> Commands tab -> Select Debug -> Drag the "Start Without Debugging" command to the Debug menu and place it where you want it to be.

As for why it happened, hard to tell.

Comment: This worked. Wierd how it not only disappeared, but it also lost the Ctrl+F5 key binding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Was it the button there before becuase I just checked on mine and saw that there was no button with Ctrl+F5, but when you do the command, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the menu bar and click **Customize...** from there you can add in any options that are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Could this happen if the current "Startup Project" - the one in bold in the Solution Explorer - is not an executable?

(I don't have access to VS to check)